# Apple's VerificationController.m failed verifying sandbox in-app purchase receipt's signature

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I was using Apple's example for locally verifying an in-app purchase receipt for a long time, but it recently stopped working on sandbox mode (works on production).

Maybe it's iOS 9.3.1 related, or they've changed something on their server side,
when trying to verify `transaction.transactionReceipt`, it fails with -

```
AssertMacros: signature_blob_ptr->version == 2,  file: ../VerificationController.m
Transaction is invalid!
```

it has a different `version` (3 instead of 2) and the rest of certificate **doesn't** match the following struct -

```
struct signature_blob {
    uint8_t version;
    uint8_t signature[128];
    uint32_t cert_len;
    uint8_t certificate[];
}
```

Any idea how to verify version 3 of Apple's in-app purchase receipt?

Comment: Have you found more information about this problem ? Im facing exactly the same situation, except that my production apps are not working either... Thank you

Comment: The accepted answer seems to reflect what happened in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've taken a look at the "version 3" signature and I have successfully reverse engineered it.

The only change is the signature length, it's now **256 bits** instead of 128. The rest of the blob should unpack and validate as expected using the code from https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/releasenotes/StoreKit/IAP_ReceiptValidation/index.html.

The signing certificate is now Apple's latest root certificate found at https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/. You will need to use the public key from that to validate the signing certificate included in the blob for version 3.

I suggest obtaining the version first before unpacking the rest of signature so you can support both version 2 and 3.

Comment: I have changed as you have said but not works for me.

Comment: @HardikShekhat please be specific. What errors are you getting? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Apple depreciated iOS6 style receipts on their server-side checks:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/44603

For now it seems like live still works, but we should probably move over to the new format

See link for details.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem you described. Everything was woking then stopped working with invalid receipt when I locally verify the receipts with Apple. Today (Apr 14, 2016) I installed the latest version of iOS (iOS 9.3.1) and the new xCode version (7.3) and the validation is working again. Did not change anything in my code!

Comment: This problem is happening to my users with iOS 9.3, so re-installing xcode would fix my problem, but not theirs... Have you found more information about this problem ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Basically apple broke all of my apps. Can't update them because just making all the artwork for the new device sizes will take a day or four, and they don't sell that well. Unfortunately I can't even make them free, since even with free in-app purchases the receipt fails.

Note to self: never make apps that are using server side functionality beyond my control again.